# Will google vision/natural language api start charging when the number of free requests are exceeded?

Tags: google-api, google-vision, google-language-api

I am preparing my first batch of requests to google vision/natural language apis. I plan on sending enough requests to exceed the free quota. I do still have my $300 in free credits in my account. So my question is: when my script is running and passes the last free request, will google then simply start deducting from my balance and allow the script to continue running seamlessly, or will it stop the script and ask me for some user input?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Straight Answer: **No**

*Here is how the billing works:*

1. Gives you a chance to use your monthly free quota
2. Once you use up your monthly free quota, Google will charge you

   2.1. If you have credits, they will accounted for the billing first
      2.2. If you don't have credits, you will be charged from the credit card